# Conjugate symbol

Tags: simplifying-expressions, expression-form

Is there a way to make mathematica display Conjugate[z] as z* or something like that? It gets very verbose when there are multiple conjugates in an expression, it becomes hard to read.

Answer (score 1):

Try this symbol for your needs:

```
ESC conj ESC
```

For instance

```
(1 - I)\[Conjugate]
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to take an existing expression and turn the Conjugate[]'s into \[Conjugate]?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to make mathematica display Conjugate[z] as z*

Another option to make all conjugates show up as star is to change the output of your cells to be `TraditonalForm`

[image]

To do this, go to option inspector and follow direction as given in [How to make all cells be displayed in TraditionalForm](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/92865/how-to-make-all-cells-be-displayed-in-traditionalform)